# How to navigate to a UIViewController programmatically?

Tags: swift, swift5

I am having difficulties navigating to a UIViewController programmatically from within another UIViewController.  I am using UIKit and Swift 5.

I have tried to follow this Medium [article](https://medium.com/better-programming/ios-programming-storyboard-navigation-vs-programmatic-navigation-cfd363de3618) but can't get it to work for me.

In my AppDelegate file I have changed the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function to this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = LoginViewController()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   return true
}
```

And then in my LoginViewController() I attempt to navigate to my DashboardViewController by doing the following:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    // present a modal with an embed UINavigationController
    let rvc = DashboardViewController()
    let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rvc)
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But DashboardViewController is never called.

What am I doing wrong and how can I change the code to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
let rvc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewControllerSwift
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rvc)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

Change `DashboardViewControllerSwift` to the name of your Swift file for your DashboardViewController, without the .swift bit. Make sure it is set as the class for DashboardViewController object in IB/Storyboard.

Also ensure the DashboardViewController object in IB/Storyboard has its Storyboard Identifier set as DashboardViewController.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm trying to avoid using storyboards as I wanted to do everything programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming across a Youtube video that helped me solve my issue.

AppDelegate

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let login = LoginViewController()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: login)
    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

LoginViewController

```
let dashboard = DashboardViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dashboard, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

1- start with SceneDelegate

`self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
 let navigation = UINavigationController()
window.rootViewController = navigation
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`

2-then 
    `let rvc = DashboardViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(rvc, animated: true)`

3- try it in viewDidLoad() if not work try it in viewWillAppear

Comment: I've just tried your solution and I am getting the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'windowScene' .

Comment: sorry add this line before this code
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

Comment: I added that line but it then returns another two errors: 'Non-void function should return a value' and about scene not being recognised.  I'm guessing it is suppose to be UIScene?